# Advertisement Manager - Dynamic Google DFP for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-dfp

I am to be soon developing a number of websites with dynamic ad models using Google's DFP service. Ideally I want to develop these websites using WordPress, I was wondering if there was any tips or brilliant plugins to allow me to show generic ad units and specific ad units on different categories, pages and posts in certain categories?

I need a default generic set of advertisments to appear in a few predefined ad slots for example: 2x MPU, 2x Leaderboard etc..

These need to change depending on what category or page you are on. The same ads need to show on posts that come from it's parent category, the same applies for sub-categories and pages with sub-pages.

There seems to be no solution out there! Just simple plugins to stick adsense codes into posts randomly it seems..

Answer (score 0):

There is no Wordpress plugin that allows different custom HTML to appear depending on what category the user is on.

Please refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category or ask me to make a Wordpress plugin for you.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is '**create custom module/plugins**'

This solution is only useful if you are not using category description any where.

you can add you advertisement code in category description, if current category has not ADV code then check in parent category ADV code, continue until root category.

For pages you can use custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a WordPress plugin that may be useful for you: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ad-code-manager/